# Apache nginx 404 Not Found

Tags: apache, nginx, http-status-code-404

When I access via browser **domain.com:8080** the site opens. But, when I access **domain.com/something**, it shows the following message:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Port 8080
```

My nginx is:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location /something{
      proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080;
  }
}
```

How Can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you installed both Apache and Nginx web servers. You should installed and enabled one of them Apache or Nginx. In your senario it showing that the Apache server is performing on 8080 port not Nginx.

Comment: Thank you, Ahad! I followed this steps https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/ and now I have now this message: "500 Internal Server Error".

Comment: In my server, I have a django website, with port 3000 and I want to install other site with wordpress. In reverse-proxy, there is a rule to django site xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000. Observation: My access to server is only remote with PuTTY.